# How to browse content of Maven target JAR in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

Is there any way to browse the content of a Maven target JAR in Eclipse?
The JARs in Maven Dependencies are possible to browse, but not my target JAR:

[image]

I am using Eclipse Kepler (build id 20130614-0229) and Maven Integration for Eclipse (version 1.4.0.20130601-0317).

(I know I can browse the JAR in other applications, but it pushes my buttons having to have to do that)

Comment: I did not try, but this looks like it might help? http://jar-plug.sourceforge.net/

Comment: you could create a maven project with the project you want to browse the jar of as its dependency

Comment: The plugin JarPlug did the trick, thanks @Behe! 
That's creative thinking right there, @BlankChisui :P

Comment: I added the info as an answer, so others can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [JarPlug Eclipse plugin](http://jar-plug.sourceforge.net/). It provides a JarPlug view, which let's you edit the content of a jar file.

It seems to be a bit dated, though.

Comment: Still did the job on Kepler :)

Answer (score 0):

I always used *[JarPlug](http://jar-plug.sourceforge.net/)*, but there is a much better alternative as I just found out: ***Remote Systems View*** (it may already be a part of your Eclipse installation or can be installed separately (called *[Remote System Explorer](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/)*):

- in the ***Local*** tree you can browse to your dir and every `[+] any.jar` **automatically can be expanded clicking on the `+` sign** and the containing files can be opened with a click
- another **advantage** over *JarPlug* is, that it **does not spoil your project dir with an ignorable *$jarplug* folder** on opening a file inside a jar

Comment: a disadvantage can be that you have to browse through the whole file system from your roots or your home folder where with *JarPlug* you can work directly on files in your project (Win-Links are not expanded, but Linux symlinks should work - which could help here)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm on Windows though, so I would prefer to use Explorer if I have to click around that much anyways.

Comment: just in case ... I guess you mean the *Project Explorer View* (*Windows Explorer* would be something I don't understand in this context). It's not much different to working with *JarPlug* where one 1. has to select the Jar and 2. open/click on the *JarPlug View* (which I always put to the *Outline* tab group) to browse the Jar. In the *Remote Systems View* which I place in the same tab group as the *Project Explorer View* you 1. have to click the view and 2. select your Jar which you can browse directly.

Comment: Well actually I meant the Windows Explorer with, for example 7-zip, to open the JARs. You're right, the Remote Systems can be handy to browse jars not included in the projects.